# Javascript nested json function: access "this"

Tags: javascript

if I have this json structure:

```
var j = {
    param1: 'hello',
    param2: 'world',
    func:   function() {
        console.log(this.param1 + ' ' + this.param2);
    }
};
```

`this` in `func` is undefined. How to access self in this json object? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I'm trying it with:

```
j.func();
```

Comment: `this` inside `j.func` should definitely refer to `j`. Can you show a case where it isn't true (and you want it to be)?

Comment: `j.func()` outputs `hello world` in my console and I see no reason why it shouldn´t.

Comment: That isn't JSON (for a start, JSON doesn't have functions). [JSON](http://json.org) is a textual notation for data exchange. What you're using there is a JavaScript [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (sometimes called an object literal). JSON is a subset of object initializer syntax.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LwmaL/ - here it works fine. But I call it correctly there. How are you caling `func`?

Comment: How do you close "works for me" questions?

Comment: @JanDvorak - if it isn't working for the OP, it's probably because of how they are calling `func()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree. But then we cannot fix the asker's problem if we don't know what it is. The best we can do is write some generic answer, and that not appreciated by many askers.

Comment: @JanDvorak - you don't immediately close questions missing one piece of information.  You ask the OP to clarify.  If they don't follow up with clarification, then you close as not a real question.

Comment: @jfriend00 FAngel did ask for clarification. Time to close already?

Comment: @JanDvorak - come on.  You want to close after only 28 mins?  I'd suggest giving it at least several hours for the OP to respond back.

Comment: @jfriend00 Understood. I'm used to fast-flowing (interactive) questions and answers. Is my expectation incorrect?

Comment: pistacchio - since you've obviously been back to this question, can you at least do us all the decency of answer the question about how you were calling `func()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is determined by how a function is called.  To answer your question, we would need to see how you are called `func()`.

If you call:

```
j.func()
```

then, `this` inside of `func` will be set to `j`.

If you call `func()` directly (which is what happens if you pass `j.func` as a callback which is then called directly by some other function), then `this` will probably be set to either `window` or `undefined` depending upon whether you are in strict mode or not.   For example:

```
function callme(callback) {
    // the context of `j` will be lost here and 
    // this will just call func() directly without setting this to j
    callback();
}

callme(j.func);
```

`this` can also be set explicitly by the caller by using `j.func.apply()` or `j.func.call()` which allow the caller to specify the desired value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need call **j.func()** and this in func will be refer to j, because it caller.